# Why can't I undo a delete vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I regularly vote for deletion on "non answers". Sometimes I am too quick; and would prefer to undo that action.

But when I click delete again; I am told that I already voted here; so there is no way to retract a delete vote?

(in contrast to close votes or flags I put up?)

Comment: Don't issue delete votes so quickly